# What is the part on older van power windows that typically fails and how do I replace it

Tags: ford, power-windows, van

Just purchased a 90s ford van, have some issue with the drivers side window ( wont go down ), actually, it will go down if you help it along. Former owner said that the passenger side window had similar problem and he fixed it, mentioned something about the "track" or "gear" he also said it's a common issue on 90s ford vans with power windows. Has anyone else had this issue? Any idea what this part is called? I tried google already but could not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple common parts
Switches - supplies power to the motor
Regulator - gears and tracks
motor (or crank) - moves the regulator

Sometimes you can take the door panel off and grease the channels up a bit and it will help.  I will use WD-40, silicon spray, white lithium grease, garage door lube, etc.  and it has helped with some of my windows that were slow/needed help.  This may be covering up an issue of the motor going out.